# Error mounting drive with fstab

Tags: mount, fsck, fstab, uuid

I have an small server in my house with an external usb 2TB hard drive:

`/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Data" UUID="eedc3098-221d-4800-b8b4-efa4fef23f5f" TYPE="ext4"`

I have the next line in `/etc/fstab`:

`UUID=eedc3098-221d-4800-b8b4-efa4fef23f5f       /home/data      ext4    defaults        0       2`

When I boot the system I get the next error:

`Unable to resolve 'UUID=eedc3098-221d-4800-b8b4-efa4fef23f5f' fsck died with exit status 8`

Then, the system ask me about root password for maintenance. If I log in like root and type:

`fsck.ext4 'UUID=eedc3098-221d-4800-b8b4-efa4fef23f5f'`

I get:

`Data: clean 99709/122101760 files, 232470354/488378368 blocks`

If I say to fsck to not ckeck the filesystem on startup (changing last 2 into a 0) the system starts properly (with the warning: `special drive UUID=eedc3098-221d-4800-b8b4-efa4fef23f5f doesn't exist`) and my partition doesn't mount. But the uuid exists in `/dev/disks/by-uuid`

How can I mount my drive properly? I thoght that maybe it can be a problem related with USB

Comment: Does it mount when you type `mount -a`?

Comment: Now what OS/distribution is that?

Comment: Debian 6.0 kernel 2.6.32-5-686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that the drive needs to be initialized by the USB driver and this initialization takes time, so that when the partitions in `fstab` are mounted, the drive isn't ready yet, but by the time you log in, the drive is ready and mounting or fsck works.

If this is the problem, try adding the option `noauto` in `/etc/fstab` and mounting the drive manually later in the boot sequence, for example in `/etc/rc.local` (or whatever your distribution offers). Alternatively, add `noauto` in `/etc/fstab` and tell udev to do the mounting, with a line like this in `/etc/udev/rules.d`:

```
KERNEL=="sd?", PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s UUID %N1", RESULT=="EEDC-3098", RUN+="mount /home/data"
```

Comment: adding the option noauto in /etc/fstab and mounting the drive manually later in the boot sequence, for example in /etc/rc.local it worked. Thx